# three.js ill formed tangents vs ill formed VertexTangentsHelper

Tags: javascript, three.js

I noticed that when I enable the "vertexTangentsHelper" on various geometry in THREE.js, I am getting ill formed tangents.

Are the tangents incorrectly computed, (As I suspect they are based on some of my shader output), or is the "vertexTangentsHelper" flawed?

As I understand it, the tangent vectors of a vertex should point along the "u" direction of the "uv" map and be perpendicular to the normal and the bitangent of that vertex. I have posted a few screen shots below to illustrate my question:

[image: correct tangents]

The above image illustrates CORRECT tangents displayed on a mesh created using "THREE.PlaneGeometry". All tangents for the mesh point along the same direction. (The mesh is 40 x 40 and has 4 height segments and 4 width segments. The tangents are 10 units long.)

[image: incorrect tangents]

The above image illustrates INCORRECT tangents displayed on a mesh created using "THREE.BoxGeometry". The tangents along the edges are not aligned with the tangents of their respected faces. (The mesh is 40 x 40 x 40 and has 4 height segments and 4 width segments for each face. The tangents are 10 units long.)

What can account for this inconsistency? Is the problem in the "computeTangents" code or in the "VertexTangentsHelper" code? Or is there something else I have not taken into account? I'm using three.js re70.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `THREE.VertexTangentsHelper`.

To compute the tangent vector for a single vertex, `Geometry.computeTangents()` averages the computed tangent vectors for each triangle sharing that vertex.

The simplest `BoxGeometry` has 8 vertices, but 12 faces. The only way it would work correctly when applied to `BoxGeometry` would be if the vertices at each corner of the box were duplicated, and not shared.

three.js r.70

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me what was happening @WestLangley. You rule!

Comment: would it be too much to ask how I could alter "Geometry.computeTangents()" to compute tangents that are not averaged and still have it compute the handedness and store that value in the w component of the corresponding tangent?

Comment: You have to do that yourself, sorry. You can try this: `( new THREE.ExplodeModifier ).modify( geometry ); geometry.computeTangents();` See the `examples/js/modifiers` directory.